# What redirect rule should I use to replace this 301 redirect, in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, virtualhost, 301-redirect

I am using this directive to redirect to `HTTPS`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName              foo.bananas.net
        Redirect                301 / https://foo.bananas.net
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when a path is used in the address bar, like `http://bananas.net/webpage`, it takes a pauses for a while before failing with `https://bananas.netwebpage` (no slash).

Should a rewrite rule be used instead?  What should it be, and are there any differences in behaviour that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use mod_rewrite, or you could use a RedirectMatch.

e.g. something like this:

```
RedirectMatch  301  ^(.*)  https://foo.bananas.net$1
```

on second thoughts, just add a "/" to the end of the Redirect rule you already have:

```
    Redirect  301  /  https://foo.bananas.net/
```

either should work.